# Accessing 32 bit program from 64 bit program through dll

Tags: c++, ms-access, x86, 64-bit, ole

We have a 32bit c++ program that uses the Microsoft access database (.mdb files) to store data. Up until 2018 Microsoft have recommended using 32bit for Access, hence this program is in 32 bit as well.

The data storing program is accessed though a 64 bit main program. These two are linked with OLE automation (COleDispatchDriver). When the main program accesses the 32bit program, it takes a while to load and the 32bit program pops on to the screen for a second before its hidden. Now we're asked if the 2 programs can be linked via a dll to prevent this.

As far as I know there's no direct way of linking 32 and 64bit programs through a dll. So the options so far are;

1. Convert 32bit program to 64
2. [Use process interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/process-interoperability)

Are there any other methods to achieve this other than the above two. If not, what would be the best approach of the two? Could you give me some examples of method 2?

Thanks.

Comment: The "best" solution depends on your needs. If there's no reason not to just convert the program (which could be as simple as a recompile), that's simplest. Furthermore, COM can be used for interprocess communication using a DLL surrogate to allow for 32-bits to 64-bits communication (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/dll-surrogates)) and has many advantages, such as easy interoperability between programming languages.

Comment: If _We have a 32bit c++ program_ means that it is yours, it should be a snap to compile it as 64-bit.

Comment: do you need a copy of Access, or can you just use the ACE data engine to pull data? You could by-pass access and use  the ACE data engine. This would only work for pulling data from .net, but if you not needing "com" automation, and just pulling data, then you may well not need to launch a working copy of access.

Comment: It's not possible to compile it in x64 without making major changes to the code. The Access DAO classes aren't supported for win64 platforms.

Comment: We need to pull and push data both.

Comment: DAO can be used with x64 bits if the x64 bit version of ACE has been installed.  But, as you note compiling the application to x64 bits is not a practical option so having x64 DAO which you get with ACE x64 does not matter then, right?  If that main  x64 program wants to, it should be able to use ACE x64 to read and pull the data, and not have to interact with the x32 bit program unless other features of that x32 program are required. But reading mdb or accDB is possible and possible without Access. You only need ACE x64 installed and that main x64 program can read + use the access file.